# Executable script in R package `inst/`

Tags: r

I am writing an R package (for internal use, will never be on CRAN). One of my functions calls a shell script containing `node.js` commands. I've put the file in `inst/node_script.sh`, so that when the package is installed I can call the script with

```
system(system.file("./node_script.sh", package = "mypackage"))
```

This works great on my development machine. But when I install the package on a test machine, `node_script.sh` is in the proper place, but it drops the executable mode, so I can't run the script without first `chmod +x ...`. Three questions:

- How can I keep the file permissions on my script file through install?
- Is there a clean way to set them afterwards? I'm using `devtools::install_github`
- Is this even the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 2):

This best one could apparently do is to use **cleanup** script https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Configure-and-cleanup

and call the installation with **--clean** argument, such as `devtools::install_github("foo/bar",args=c("--clean"))`

If your /tmp has *noexec* flag like me, then you are out of luck.

Here is a related question [R package that delivers executables residing in /inst](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47304933/r-package-that-delivers-executables-residing-in-inst)

Answer (score 1):

I got this working (kind of) by including a 'chmod' command immediately before the call.

```
node_file <- system.file("./node_script.sh", package = "mypackage")
Sys.chmod(node_file, mode = "0555")
system(node_file)
```

It seems very hacky to me, and I'd love an alternative.