# R package that delivers executables residing in /inst

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

I would like to create an **R package** that relies on executables that I put into the ***/inst*** folder.
However, whatever I put in ***/inst*** loses the execution bit after the package is installed, hence the **binaries become non-executable** due to the missing bit. Is there a way to preserve the file mode for files in ***/inst*** or these execution bits need to be added post installation? If so, anyone knows how?

Appreciate any inputs

Comment: I think you should put it in `/data`, see http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html

Comment: When i put the stuff in **/data**, then it doesn't even show up in the package folder after installation.

Comment: Same question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47083455/executable-script-in-r-package-inst   Unfortunately no answer

Comment: This is by design. You're encouraged _not to do this_ [by CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html#Package-structure) and your pkg will likely never see CRAN if you do.

Comment: The target audience of this package is internal users, so it doesn't need to see CRAN. After going through the document, it looks like the only option is to use **cleanup** script to add the execution bits after installation. Is that correct?